# Unity3d - Random Start direction and ForceMode.Impulse?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a cube. A script is attached to it. I want, that the cube gets an impulse at the start in a random direction. My problem is the addForce. I don't know what to add there.

```
public Transform myObject;

void Start () {
    Vector3 randomDirection = new Vector3(0f,0f,Random.Range(-359, 359)); 
    myObject.Rotate (randomDirection);

    myObject.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.?????? * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For random you want

```
myObject.rigid body.AddForce(Random.Range(0, 10), Random.Range(0, 10), Random.Range(0, 10), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

The code is saying, give me a random force value for the `x, y, z`.

**Rotation has nothing to do with it**. If you push a cat from a random Angle, you add force to the cat. You don't need to rotate the cat to push it. Although you shouldn't go around pushing cats.

If you insist on random rotation then make your object fire off forwards:

```
 myObject.rigid body.AddForce(myObject.transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: But the cube is not moving to bottom right. I want a random degree.

Comment: What is "bottom right"? Again, when you set force on x,y,z it will be random.

Comment: I mean, the object is moving only in this degress: 0 - 45

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to say, that I want to move the object only in the x and y axis.

Comment: Then make the z always 0.

Answer (score 0):

`transform.forward` is a property on `Transform` that represents the direction the object is facing. In the Editor, it is represented by the blue axis on the object's transform handle.

If you use it in your script, the object will have a force applied to it in the random direction determined by the `myObject.Rotate(...)` line.